# New Spotify User Profile Request

Tags: ios, sdk, spotify

Could someone please show an example code on how to pull Spotify user information now that [SPTRequest userinformation....] is deprecated.  Specifically which of these to implement and how...

```
+ (NSURLRequest *)createRequestForCurrentUserWithAccessToken:(NSString *)accessToken error:(NSError **)error;

+(void)requestCurrentUserWithAccessToken:(NSString *)accessToken callback:(SPTRequestCallback)block;

+(void)requestUser:(NSString *)username withAccessToken:(NSString *)accessToken callback:(SPTRequestCallback)block;
```

and what are the implications for....

```
+ (instancetype)userFromData:(NSData *)data
            withResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
                   error:(NSError **)error;
```

Using only intermediate ObjC skills here so please detail.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the class methods in `SPTUser` to get a user, easiest is to do a:

```
[SPTUser requestUser:@"username"
     withAccessToken:@"...."
            callback:^(NSError *error, SPTUser *user) {
    NSLog(@"got user %@", user);
}];
```

The reason we have a `userFromData...` is to parse the response from the Web API, requestUser internally uses the `createRequestFor...` method to create a `NSURLRequest` for the Web API Resource, issues that call, then calls the `userFromData...` to parse the response into a `SPTUser` object and finally calls your callback with that user object.

Comment: Has this process changed at all with SDK Beta 9??

Comment: This should be exactly the same